What happens if we set @SessionAttributes("order") on controller and @ModelAttribute("order") before a method together?
I am new to spring. As i know, methods annotated with @ModelAttribute("order") will be called every time a request reaches the controller. But what if we also set the same attribute in session as @SessionAttributes("order"):
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/design")
@SessionAttributes("order")
public class DesignTacoController {
  @ModelAttribute(name = "order")
  public Order order() {
    return new Order();
  }

  public String processDesign(
      @Valid Taco design, Errors errors, 
      @ModelAttribute Order order) {

  }
}

So the 1st time a request comes in, a new order is added to the session. The 2nd time another request comes in, will a new order be created again and overwrite the current one in session? And where does the order in @ModelAttribute Order order comes from? Model or session?

What "other request" from the same client, different client? Where does the request come from?
